# How do I define a data type that only accepts numbers?

Tags: haskell, types, typeclass

I am attempting to create a data type, `Point`, that takes three numbers for its constructor. Initially, I had written

```
data Point = Point Double Double Double
```

but I ran into some issues when certain pieces of code expected `Int`s.

So I changed it to

```
data Point a = Point a a a
```

but now I would like to enforce that `a` is an instance (?) of `Num` - I only want to accept numbers in the constructor.

Is this possible? If not, what is the accepted practice? How many times did I use the wrong word to describe something?

Comment: The right answer is to add the constraint to things that use the type, e.g. `addPoints :: Num a => Point a -> Point a -> Point a`. Don't enforce it as part of the data type declaration itself (there are two ways to do that; both are equally wrong here, though one is a bit more equal).

Comment: @shachaf Could you touch on the reasoning behind that?

Comment: @sdasdadas I have elaborated on that in my answer now. See point 4 in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Yes! At least if you allow yourself some language extensions GHC provide. You basically have four options where one is bad, one is better, one is not as obvious as the other two and one is the Right Way™.

### 1. The Bad

You can write

```
{-# LANGUAGE DatatypeContexts #-}
data Num a => Point a = Point a a a
```

This will make it so that the constructor `Point` can only be called with `Num a` values. However, it does not limit the contents of a `Point` value to `Num a` values. This means that if you further down the road want to add two points, you would still have to do

```
addPoints :: Num a => Point a -> Point a -> Point a
addPoints (Point x1 y1 z1) {- ... -}
```

Do you see the extra `Num a` declaration? That shouldn't be necessary since we know a `Point` can only contain `Num a` anyway, but that's the way `DatatypeContexts` work! You have to put constraints on every function needing it anyway.

This is why, if you enable `DatatypeContexts`, GHC will scream at you a little for using a "misfeature."

### 2. The Better

The solution involves turning on GADTs. Generalised algebraic datatypes allow you to do what you want. Your declaration would then look like

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
data Point a where
  Point :: Num a => a -> a -> a -> Point a
```

When using GADTs, you declare constructors by stating their type signature instead, almost like when creating typeclasses.

Constraints on GADT constructors have the benefit that they carry over to the value that is created – in this case that means both you *and* the compiler knows that the only existing `Point a`s have members who are `Num a`s. You can therefore write your `addPoint` function as just

```
addPoints :: Point a -> Point a -> Point a
addPoints (Point x1 y1 z1) {- ... -}
```

without the irritating extra constraint.

#### Side note: Deriving Classes for GADTs

Deriving classes with GADTs (or any non-Haskell-98 type) requires an extra language extension and it is not as smooth sailing as with normal ADTs. The principle is

```
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving #-}
deriving instance Show (Point a)
```

This will just blindly generate code for the `Show` class, and it is up to you to make sure that code typechecks.

### 3. The Obscure

As *shachaf* points out in the comments to this post, you can get the relevant parts of GADT behaviour while retaining traditional `data` syntax by enabling `ExistentialQuantification` in GHC. This makes the `data` declaration as simple as

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}
data Point a = Num a => Point a a a
```

## 4. The Correct

However, none of the solutions above is what the consensus in the community is. If you ask knowledgeable people (thanks to *edwardk* and *startling* in the #haskell channel for sharing their knowledge), they will tell you **not to constrain your types at all**. They will tell you that you should define your type as

```
data Point a = Point a a a
```

and then constrain any functions operating on `Point`s, like for example the one to add two points together:

```
addPoints :: Num a => Point a -> Point a -> Point a
addPoints (Point x1 y1 z1) {- ... -}
```

The reason to not constrain your types is that when doing so, you *seriously* limit your options for using the types later, in ways you probably don't expect. For example, creating a Functor instance for your point might be useful, like so:

```
instance Functor Point where
  fmap f (Point x y z) = Point (f x) (f y) (f z)
```

and then you can do something like approximating a `Point Double` with a `Point Int` by simply evaluating

```
round <$> Point 3.5 9.7 1.3
```

which will produce

```
Point 4 10 1
```

This would not be possible if you constrained your `Point a` to `Num a`s only, because you can't define a Functor instance for such a constrained type. You woud have to create your own `pointFmap` function, which would go against all reusability and modularity that Haskell stands for.

Perhaps even more convincing, if you ask the user for coordinates but the user only enters two of them, you can model that as a

```
Point (Just 4) (Just 7) Nothing
```

and easily convert it to a point on the XY plane in 3D space by mapping

```
fromMaybe 0 <$> Point (Just 4) (Just 7) Nothing
```

which will return

```
Point 4 7 0
```

Note here that this latter example wouldn't work for two reasons if you had a `Num a` constraint on your point:

1. You would not be able to define a Functor instance for your Point, and
2. You would not at all be able to store `Maybe a` coordinates in your point.

And this is just *one* useful example of the many you would forego if you applied the `Num a` constraint on the point.

On the flip side of this, what do you *gain* by constraining your types? I can think of three reasons:

1. "I don't want to accidentally create a `Point String` and try to manipulate it as a number." You won't be able to. The type system will stop you anyway.
2. "But it's for documentation purposes! I want to show that a Point is a collection of numeric values." ...except when it is not, such as `Point [-3, 3] [5] [2, 6]` which expresses alternative coordinates on the axes, which may or may not all be valid.
3. "I don't want to keep adding `Num` constraints to all my functions!" Fair enough. You can copy and paste them from `ghci` in this case. A little keyboard work is worth all the benefits, in my opinion.

Comment: There's no need to introduce GADT syntax for this -- you can just as well write `data Point a = Num a => Point a a a`, with just ExistentialQuantification in GHC. On the other hand, this is still not a good solution for this sort of situation. You should just write the constraints when you use `Point` values.

Comment: @shachaf Not too surprisingly, there's more to GHC than I knew! I've also heard your argument often. Is there anywhere I can read about the benefits/drawbacks of constraining each function instead of the constructors? Is it equally bad to create a `data Pt = Pt Double Double Double`? If that's not bad, I have a hard time seeing why making the type a little more general would be bad. (But if I can convince myself that what you are saying is correct, I will gladly add it to my answer as another alte.)

Comment: You don't need `DatatypeContexts` with `ExistentialQuantification`; really, you don't need it for anything other than plain old datatype contexts (and thank goodness for that).

Comment: @AntalS-Z Thanks, I wrote that part of the answer a little prematurely. (Before I had toyed around with `ExistentialQuantification` to figure out how it works in this case.)

Comment: Great answer, particularly if applied to other data types. For points – well, if you do parameterise them on the coordinate-axis type, then I agree that type shouldn't be constrained. However, I tend to say it's probably not good to parameterise `Point` in the first place, because this really makes it a literal triplefold _cartesian product_ of the coordinate type. Which is not necessarily a mathematical point of view you want to emphasise when dealing with affine/vector spaces. Those are supposed to be basis invariant, which is only possible if the coordinate type approximates ℝ (or ℂ, ...).

Comment: Thanks very much for both the depth of this answer and your appended part 4. It makes more sense now.

Answer (score 5):

You can use GADT to specify the constraint:

```
{-# Language GADTs #-}

data Point a where
  Point :: (Num a) => a -> a ->  a -> Point a
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Num` typeclass to enforce `Num` constraint on your datatype. The usual syntax would be something like:

```
data MyTypeClass a => MyDataType a = MyDataTypeConstructor1 a|MyDataTypeConstructor2 a a|{- and so on... -}
```

In your case, you can do

```
data Num a => Point a = Point a a a
```

Read more about [data type specifications](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#x10-680004.2) and [LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses). [Real World Haskell](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/using-typeclasses.html) also mentions this.

**EDIT**

As mentioned by [shachaf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712548/shachaf), this is not quite valid haskell2010, though the specification mentions it. I should also note that this form is seldom used and the preferred way to enforce these constraints through functions than through typeclasses/datatypes, since they introduce an additional dependency on types.

Comment: This is invalid Haskell 2010. It was valid Haskell 98, but it was removed in Haskell 2010 because it doesn't do anything useful.

Comment: @shachaf, I was not aware of that - I mean, Haskell2010 still shows that information (from my link). I'll update my answer, thanks.