# Maintaining expressiveness through type aliases (How much should I use type aliases?)

Tags: haskell

this is mostly a stylistic question (so perhaps not the best for SO; but I don't know of anywhere else to ask);

In my problem space I've noticed that many of my Data-structures represent Bifunctors; in many cases they're Bifunctors over a single specific type. For example:

```
data Coord = Coord Int Int
data Range = Range Coord Coord
```

etc.

I've found it useful to map over the components of these using `first, second` from [Bifunctor](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Bifunctor.html#t:Bifunctor); this of course requires me to define them as Bifunctors:

```
data Coord a b = Coord a b
instance Bifunctor Coord where ...
data Range a b = Range a b
instance Bifunctor Range where ...
```

I've found several such cases where the types have the exact same structure; essentially `Pair a = Pair a a` (or even the tuple (a, a) where the data is a pair of two elements of the same type. It seems unfortunate to me that in order to benefit from Bifunctor (and all its associated helpers and lenses) I need to now specify `Range Coord Coord` as all of my types; so I've started using type aliases `type Range = Pair Coord Coord` and `type Coord = Pair Int Int`; this allows me to not have a bunch of redundant definitions; however when pattern matching each case is now the non-descriptive `f (Pair a b) = ...` where I gain no knowledge about what is inside.

I've learned through reading [this informative answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19649967/how-do-i-define-a-data-type-that-only-accepts-numbers) that types themselves shouldn't impose restrictions on what they contain; so I suppose I'm okay with having something like `data Range a b = Range a b`,

I suppose my question boils down to; is there an established way to handle deduplication over similar data-structures while still maintaining the expressiveness of good type names/aliases?

Right now I have:

```
data Range a b = Range a b
type CrdRange = Range Coord Coord
```

But I don't love that the type is `CrdRange` but it's unpacked with `Range` instead of `CrdRange`.

Note that I also do have one or two special instances as well; for instance I have a special `instance Ord Coord`.

Comment: is it not possible for your data types to 'derive' bifunctor (like they can do with standard functors?)

Comment: You ask how to deduplicate, but then don't show any duplication. Perhaps you can say a bit more about what repetition you are trying to cut out on.

Comment: Yeah; I don't think I'm really sure of what I'm asking either; this can probably be closed. I ended up just defining a few type aliases and dealing with the repetition.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing that comes to mind is `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving`

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}

import Data.Bifunctor

newtype Coord a b = Coord (a,b) deriving Bifunctor
newtype Range a b = Range (a,b) deriving Bifunctor

type CrdRange = Range (Coord Int Int) (Coord Int Int)
```

Comment: Thanks; I'm aware of GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving; this works of course, but now the unpacking is `Range (a, b)` for type CrdRange; which still has the name mismatch and adds in the redundant brackets as well. Definitely functional; but not ideal.

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with the **lens** or [**microlens**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/microlens) libraries, perhaps you could define lenses/traversals of the form `coordToTuple :: Traversal' Coord (Int,Int)` and then use the [`over`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.1/docs/Control-Lens-Setter.html#v:over) function like `over coordToTuple (first someFunction) someCoord`.

---

To avoid having to remember the names of multiple lenses, you could define a multi-parameter typeclass like

```
class MonoPair c a | c -> a where
    monoPair :: Traversal' c (a,a)
```

and define instances for your types.

---

Alternative idea: define your types as newtypes around [`V2`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/linear-1.20.5/docs/Linear-V2.html#t:V2) from **linear**. This only makes sense if your types behave like vectors. `V2` is not a bifunctor, but you can use `GeneralizeNewtypeDeriving` to derive the [`R1`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/linear-1.20.5/docs/Linear-V2.html#t:R1) and `R2` typeclasses for getting/setting components.

To avoid awkward parentheses while pattern-matching, define auxiliary [pattern synonyms](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#pattern-synonyms) like

```
pattern CoordV2 x y = Coord (V2 x y)
```